# Laravel 5.0 extending the 'Logout' functionality

Tags: php, mysql, session, laravel, authentication

I recently set sessions to save to the database and added a user_id field to the sessions table so that I may display the names of logged in users.  In order to get laravel to save the id of a user when they log in(given laravel doesn't look for a user_id column regularly), I had to add a bit of code to the Authenticate.php file to handle that.

Now, I am attempting to set the user_id field to `null` when the user logs out because presently, since the user_id field still contains the user's id even after they log out, it still displays them as logged in even though they are no longer logged in.  I am looking to extend the auth/logout functionality without actually touching the vendor files to include my function to set the user_id to null on logout.

Where might I add this function to exactly?  In the AuthController.php file?  In routes.php adding in my own declaration of the auth/logout route?

If you have any questions for me or need me to better explain anything, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you logout the user? The ID should be cleared after the logout, I'm not sure how you're still getting that.

Comment: The sessions includes guest users as well.  I just need it to state(in regards to user_id) that the user is now a guest user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put following function in `AuthController.php` to override default function from `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait. And you can change it as per your need.

```
/**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getLogout()
    {
        $this->auth->logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }
```

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid right now for not thinking of simply copying the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php function to override it directly in the AuthController.php file... Thanks mate.